# NSIS: can't import tinker

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pynsist

I would like to build my program that uses `matplotlib`, which requires `tkinter`. 
The problem is that I can't include `tkinter`, as it is not on pyPi (and it has now wheels).

I use Pynsist to build an NSIS installer. Here is the cfg:

```
[Application]
name=SineWave
version=1.0
# How to launch the app - this calls the 'main' function from the 'myapp' package:
entry_point=main:main
icon=sinewave.ico

[Python]
version=3.6.5

[Include]
# Packages from PyPI that your application requires, one per line
# These must have wheels on PyPI:
pypi_wheels = numpy==1.16.1
    matplotlib==3.0.3
    pyparsing==2.4.0
    cycler==0.10.0
    six==1.11.0
    python-dateutil==2.8.0
    kiwisolver==1.0.1
    anaconda-project==0.8.2
```

If I run the builded exe it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Novot\AppData\Local\SineWave\SineWave.launch.pyw", line 31, in <module>
    from main import main
  File "C:\Users\Novot\AppData\Local\SineWave\pkgs\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Novot\AppData\Local\SineWave\pkgs\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2372, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "C:\Users\Novot\AppData\Local\SineWave\pkgs\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 207, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "C:\Users\Novot\AppData\Local\SineWave\pkgs\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "C:\Users\Novot\AppData\Local\SineWave\pkgs\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tkinter as Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

And also, is there a way to import all libraries that another one requires?

Comment: I don't see how this warrants the NSIS tag

Comment: It does everything it needs to, but I can't import the tinker module...... @Anders

Comment: I mean, you have not posted any NSIS code and nothing about your question seems relevant to NSIS. You would not add a Windows tag just because you are running on Windows etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the documentation:
[Pynsist documentation](https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#packaging-with-tkinter)

**"Because Pynsist makes use of the “bundled” versions of Python the tkinter module isn’t included by default. If your application relies on tkinter for a GUI then you need to find the following assets..."**

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer, as requested by this [StackOverflow help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.